# Error: ffmpeg exited with code 1: Option framerate not found

Tags: node.js, ffmpeg

Error: ffmpeg exited with code 1: Option framerate not found.
I am adding audio with images but getting error,Please help me

```
ffmpeg().addInput(__dirname + "/images/FullSizeRender-%1d.jpg")
  .complexFilter([
  //  " -framerate 1",
    {
    filter: "zoompan",
    options: {
      x: "iw/2-(iw/zoom/2)",
      y: "ih/2-(ih/zoom/2)",
      z: "if(lte(zoom,1.0),1.5,max(1.001,zoom-0.0040))",
      d: "125",
      s: "200x200"
    }
  }])
  // here we will give the audio path
  .addInput('audio path')
  .addInputOption(["-framerate 1" ])
  .addOutputOption(["-c:v libx264", "-r 30", "-pix_fmt yuv420p"])
  .addOption("-crf", 26)
  .format("mp4")
  .videoBitrate("1024k")
  .videoCodec("mpeg4")
  .on("error", function (er) {
    console.log("error occured: " + er.message, er);

  })
  .on("end", function (data) {
    console.log("created video has been completed");

    new ffmpeg({
        source: finalVideoPath,
        nolog: true,
      })
      .mergeAdd(__dirname + "/video/video.mp4")
      .mergeAdd(__dirname + "/video/video2.mp4")
      .mergeToFile(margeVideoPath, function (data) {
        console.log("marge video", data);
      });

      setTimeout(() => {
        //UploadVideoS3(margeVideoPath);
      }, 10000);

  }).save(finalVideoPath);
```

I am adding audio with images but getting error,Please help me

Comment: `addInputOption(["-framerate 1" ])` belongs to the first input (image) not the audio. However, zoompan will override that. What are you trying to do?

Comment: @Gyan I have created a video with images successfully but I am creating a video with images and also want to add audio where i can do change for this solution.please help me

Comment: Don't know how node.js wrapper works but it could be as simple as swapping `addInput('audio path') 
  .addInputOption(["-framerate 1" ])`

Comment: @Gyan i have swapped getting different    -  Error: ffmpeg exited with code 1: Cannot find a matching stream for unlabeled input pad 3 on filter Parsed_concat_0